# ZSH Alias fires terminal-notifier but not command that spawned it

Tags: function, gulp, sh, zsh, zshrc

OK, so I asked this question a couple of days ago, but fluffed it up a little, so I deleted it and am going to try and ask for help again...

I have an alias in my .zshrc;

```
alias gulp='gulp-notice'
```

This in turn fires a function;

```
gulp-notice ()
{
  notifier-around gulp "Gulp" "gulp $*"
}
```

which in turn fires this function

```
notifier-around ()
{
  GROUP_ID=$1
  TITLE=$2
  COMMAND=$3 $4 $5 $6 $7 $8 $9
  terminal-notifier -title $COMMAND -message 'Finished' -appIcon https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/564x/b5/5a/18/b55a1805f5650495a74202279036ecd2.jpg && terminal-notifier -title $COMMAND -message 'Complete' -appIcon https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/564x/b5/5a/18/b55a1805f5650495a74202279036ecd2.jpg || terminal-notifier -title $COMMAND -message 'Failed' -appIcon https://media3.giphy.com/media/10ECejNtM1GyRy/200_s.gif
}
```

So the variables work out like this (using the gulp-notice function)

```
GROUP_ID is gulp
TITLE is "Gulp" (without the quote marks)
COMMAND is "gulp $*" (the output without the quote marks)
```

Now my problem is this... When I used to run this script in BASH it would execute the gulp command and terminal notifier would do it's thing (telling me if gulp had failed or succeeded)

```
gulp
```

would fire `gulp` and the necessary notifications depending on the situation

```
gulp sass
```

would fire `gulp sass` and the necessary notifications depending on the situation

Now I have moved over to ZSH, the script JUST fires the terminal-notification and nothing else. Could someone point me in the right direction as I don't understand why the scripting should be so different between two terminal apps

**UPDATE**
I now have working code, but I can't run gulp tasks such as SASS or JS (`gulp sass` or `gulp js`). My revised code is as follow

```
notifier-around ()
{
  GROUP_ID=$1
  TITLE=$2
  COMMAND="$3 $4 $5 $6 $7 $8 $9"
  COMMAND_NO_WHITE_SPACE="$(echo -e "${COMMAND}" | sed -e 's/[[:space:]]*$//')" //strips the white space from the end of the VAR
  PROGRESS="https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/564x/b5/5a/18/b55a1805f5650495a74202279036ecd2.jpg"
  FAIL="https://media3.giphy.com/media/10ECejNtM1GyRy/200_s.gif"
  terminal-notifier -group "$GROUP_ID" -title "$TITLE" -message "Starting" -appIcon "$PROGRESS" && $COMMAND_NO_WHITE_SPACE && terminal-notifier -group "$GROUP_ID" -title "$TITLE" -message "Complete" -appIcon "$PROGRESS" || terminal-notifier -group "$GROUP_ID" -title "$TITLE" -message "Failure" -appIcon "$FAIL"
}

gulp-notice ()
{
  notifier-around gulp "Gulp Build" "gulp $*"
}

alias gulp='gulp-notice'
```

Any ideas on how to get it to recognise the additional tasks, as I can't run `gulp --tasks` either...

Comment: As I mentioned in your last question, it has to be `COMMAND="$3 $4 $5 $6 $7 $8 $9"`; otherwise, you are attempting to run `$4` with arguments `$5, ..., $9` in an environment where `COMMAND=$3`, and `COMMAND` is not set when you run `terminal-notifier`.

Comment: Thanks @chepner, I wasn't re-posting to be rude, I think I just made a mess of the original question. You're feedback, as ever, has been invaluable :)

Comment: So the code is now "working", but I am back to my old friend `notifier-around:5: command not found: gulp`. Now my PATH includes `/usr/local/bin` which is where GULP lives, but even if I explicitly state `/usr/local/bin/gulp` in the function it still tells me it can't find GULP. If I execute `/usr/local/bin/gulp` without my function active it works fine... Any ideas?

Comment: @Takuhii : I don't see in your code where you actually would invoke /usr/local/bin/gulp. In particular, you never evaluate $COMMAND. It would help if you run the whole invokation under `set -x`, so that we can see what is going on.

Comment: Sorry, I probably didn't communicate that very well... My script itself executes `gulp` as it should be coming out of a location in my PATH variable... if I run gulp outside of the function, i.e. manually, it works fine... It's almost like zsh runs my function in a sandbox, and I can't interact with the outside world. I thought it might be iTerm2, but I don't know... I will run set -x and post my results...

Comment: `+-zsh:2> gulp-notice`  
`+gulp-notice:2> notifier-around gulp 'Gulp Build' 'gulp '`  
`+notifier-around:2> GROUP_ID=gulp`  
`+notifier-around:3> TITLE='Gulp Build'`  
`+notifier-around:4> COMMAND='gulp       '`  
`+notifier-around:5> terminal-notifier -group gulp -title 'Gulp Build' -message Starting -appIcon https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/564x/b5/5a/18/b55a1805f5650495a74202279036ecd2.jpg`

Comment: It was the whitespace generated by the lack of variable

Comment: But I have now uncovered another problem

Answer (score 0):

So I finally fixed it;

```
notifier-around ()
{
  GROUP_ID="$1"
  TITLE="$2"
  COMMAND="$3"
  COMMAND_NO_WHITE_SPACE="$(echo -e "${COMMAND}" | sed -e 's/[[:space:]]*$//')" //strips the white space from the end of the VAR
  PROGRESS="https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/564x/b5/5a/18/b55a1805f5650495a74202279036ecd2.jpg"
  FAIL="https://media3.giphy.com/media/10ECejNtM1GyRy/200_s.gif"
  terminal-notifier -group "$GROUP_ID" -title "$TITLE" -message "Starting" -appIcon "$PROGRESS" && "${=COMMAND_NO_WHITE_SPACE}" && terminal-notifier -group "$GROUP_ID" -title "$TITLE" -message "Complete" -appIcon "$PROGRESS" || terminal-notifier -group "$GROUP_ID" -title "$TITLE" -message "Failure" -appIcon "$FAIL"
}

gulp-notice ()
{
  notifier-around gulp "Gulp Build" "gulp $*"
}

alias gulp='gulp-notice'
```

You'll see that I am stripping out the trailing whitespace with;
`COMMAND_NO_WHITE_SPACE="$(echo -e "${COMMAND}" | sed -e 's/[[:space:]]*$//')"` as that seemed to be causing issues

You'll also see I changed `"$COMMAND_NO_WHITE_SPACE"` to `"${=COMMAND_NO_WHITE_SPACE}"` The `${=` is to split a variable by $IFS. this is giving ZSH the kick up the ass it needs to recognise I am trying to add a parameter to my command